# scntool: failed to convert file with failure reason: *** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, collada

I'm working on an iOS 11.3 SceneKit based project under Xcode 9.3.  I have several 3D models in the .dae file format.

Whenever I build the project, one of the models doesn't get copied into the final iOS bundle.  Digging into the errors, I get the following error in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase:

```
Copy SceneKit assets Models.scnassets ...in /Users/andrew/Documents/src/gordon/gordon

scntool: failed to convert file with failure reason: *** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds
scntool: Conversion failed, will simply copy input to output.
scntool: Copy failed file:///Users/andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gordon-hewludfnoywxcpegodbqhgocatbu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gordon.app/Models.scnassets/gordon/gordon-old.dae -> file:///Users/andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gordon-hewludfnoywxcpegodbqhgocatbu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gordon.app/Models.scnassets/gordon/gordon-old.dae error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “gordon-old.dae” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gordon-hewludfnoywxcpegodbqhgocatbu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gordon.app/Models.scnassets/gordon/gordon-old.dae, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd013e5c080 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Basically, it acts like there's something wrong with the **gordon-old.dae** file.  When I click on the file in Xcode, it displays a preview of the model, as expected.

If I manually convert the file to scn with "**xcrun scntool --convert gordon-old.dae  --format scn --output gordon-old.scn**", Xcode again previews the model correctly.  In this case, however, the model is displayed correctly within the app as well, but only the first/main geometry is present in the .scn file.

If I run the normal dae conversion that Xcode runs, when it asks you if you want to keep the original file or not, with "**xcrun scntool --convert gordon-old.dae  --format dae --output gordon-new.dae**", the app build and install again works fine.  Clicking on the **gordon-new.dae** in Xcode again displays a good preview, and the model looks ok in the app.

However in that case, all of the geometries I use for blend shapes are assigned names like "geometry114" instead of "mouthSmileLeft", which I had it named.

And the crazy thing here is that all of the other models work fine without me running any command-line things.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have this problem before in large size DAE files, so I use terminal command to convert it but i notice that materials I gone then I knew something wrong in the command line it self cause it does not set the resources to the correct path, after many trial and errors I found out that the correct way to do it is

```
xcrun scntool --convert INPUT.dae --format scn --output OUT.scn --asset-catalog-path .
```

The dot at the end of the command line is very important it means you will set resources to same location

If you don’t set the —asset-catalog-path . You will have no materials

By comparing 2 Output files, one with correct conversion and the other without

You will notice a missing line “path”, this line “path”, tells the SCN file to search the materials in the correct location

Mistaken Out.scn

```
    },
    {   "$class" = :false;
        NS.keys = ( :false );
        NS.objects = ( :false );
    },
    "AMS02Coil.png",
    {   "$classes" = ( "NSMutableDictionary", "NSDictionary", "NSObject" );
        "$classname" = "NSMutableDictionary";
    },
```

Correct Out.scn File

```
    },
    {   "$class" = :false;
        NS.keys = ( :false );
        NS.objects = ( :false );
    },
    "path",
    "AMS02Coil.png",
    {   "$classes" = ( "NSMutableDictionary", "NSDictionary", "NSObject" );
        "$classname" = "NSMutableDictionary";
    },
```

List Of all scntool Command Options is located at This Location
https://gist.github.com/matux/4a30c4b4b29d636fe6847b6a3234bc4f