# m1 pro build iOS app runtime error: COLLADA files are not supported on this platform

Tags: xcode, 3d, scenekit, apple-m1, collada

In **m1pro** chip (my new MacBook Pro 14'), iOS App load dae file error.  Crash both in  simulator and devices.

```
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/3dmodel.dae")!   //crash here, error "COLLADA files are not supported on this platform."
        ...other code...
    }
```

But the same code works well with **intel** chip (MacBook Pro 13' 2017) built iOS APP

Question: **Does the apple m1pro chip not support dae files?**   But c4d works well in m1pro.

Environment:

- MacOS12.1
- xcode 13.1

Have Tried:

- MacOS12.0.1   -> MacOS12.1
- xcode 12 -> xcode 13
- Simulator and iOS Devices
- iOS 14 -> iOS 15

all above not works.

Comment: I found similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50377579/scntool-failed-to-convert-file-with-failure-reason-nssingleobjectarray.   not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resovled.   by doing this

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Because I found warnings in build time.
[build warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlvKP.png)

notice that xcode actually convert dae file to scn file in build time, but the warnings said converting failed.
then i tried to run  xcrun scntool, it got errors.

```
xcrun scntool
scntool: warning: Could not find bundle inside /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
 at path /Library/Developer/SharedFrameworks/ModelIO.framework
scntool: warning: Could not find bundle inside /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
 at path /Library/Developer/SharedFrameworks/SceneKit.framework
scntool: warning: Could not find bundle inside /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
 at path /Library/Developer/SharedFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework
scntool: warning: Could not find bundle inside /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
 at path /Library/Developer/SharedFrameworks/Jet.framework
scntool: warning: Could not find bundle inside /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
 at path /Library/Developer/SharedFrameworks/SpriteKit.framework
usage: scntool --convert file --format format [--output file]
scntool: error: (null)
```

something wrong with the ComandLineTool, so i did the steps as this post. [command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66664207/command-line-tools-are-already-installed-use-software-update-to-install-updat)

it works. build app without scntool warnings, and the app runs well.